# Python 3 program with nested list, prompted 'tuple' class error when compiling

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors, tuples

Found the problem in the function `HerusticSort`, I'll check that.

---

I wrote a piece of python code using nested list like:

```
opentab = [[start], [0], [None]]

node = opentab[0].pop(0)
```

But when executing the code, it prompted

> File "\Herustic Search.py", line 97, in HerusticSearchA
>
> node = opentab[0].pop(0)
>
> **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'**

It's very weird because I didn't change it's class and I've already define it as nested list.

---

After the problem, I set an assertion to make sure it's right.

```
assert isinstance(opentab[0], list)
```

And of course now I got an **AssertionError**

I also tried in IDLE one by one, and no problem.

I just put complete code piece here, I don't know why this happened...

---

```
def HerusticSearchA(start, end):
    '''
    
    '''

    def H_Function(state, depth):
        '''
        state is a 3 x 3 list, stands for the puzzle state.
        returns the herustic assessment value
        g for the depth of the node, h for the incorrect tile number
        '''
        crit = copy.deepcopy(end)
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(state)):
            for j in range(len(state[0])):
                if state[i][j] - crit[i][j] != 0:
                    count += 1
        return depth + count


    #1. Variables
    #[[state], [value], [father]]
    opentab = [[start], [0], [None]]
    close = [[], [], []]

    depth = 0
    done = False

    print(start, end)
    while len(opentab[0]) > 0:
    #2. Nothing to continue
        if opentab == [[], [], []]:
            return None
    #3. remove n from OPEN
        assert isinstance(opentab[0], list)

        node = opentab[0].pop(0)
        nodevalue = opentab[1].pop(0)
        father = opentab[2].pop(0)
        close[0].append(node)
        close[1].append(nodevalue)
        close[2].append(father)
    #4. Got result
        if node == target:
            close[0].append(node)
            close[1].append(nodevalue)
            close[2].append(father)
            done = True
            break
    #5. Extract followers
        else:
            nexts = NextStep(node)
            for subnode in nexts:
                newvalue = H_Function(subnode, depth)
                #conditions:
                #6.
                if subnode not in opentab[0] and subnode not in close[0]:
                    opentab[0].append(subnode)
                    opentab[1].append(newvalue)
                    opentab[2].append(node)
                #7.
                if subnode in opentab[0]:
                    idx = opentab[0].index(subnode)
                    if newvalue < opentab[1][idx]:
                        opentab[1][idx] = newvalue
                        opentab[2][idx] = node
                #8.
                if subnode in close[0]:
                    idx = close[0].index(subnode)
                    if newvalue < close[1][idx]:
                        close[1][idx] = newvalue
                        close[2][idx] = node
        #9. sort opentab
        HerusticSort(opentab, 1)
        depth += 1

    return close
```

Comment: There's something else wrong that you haven't posted.

Comment: Something else? Only this showed up. But ok, I'll put on the whole function.

Comment: If you run this code by itself- no other libs or source- and call "HerusticSearchA()" with some parameters, then you get the `AssertionError`? If so, I suspect you have a wildly broken python build. If not, please try to put together a minimal example that actually does produce the behavior you see (this one's definitely not minimal, because the `H_Function` bit is never used by the given code).

Comment: You can't run this code by itself as `target`, `NextStep` (at least) are global.  The data structures in here are quite hard to sort out as well.  Instead of nesting lists, why not have a dictionary of lists? `d['state']=[start]`, `d['value']=[value]` etc.

Comment: What values does `NextStep()` return ?

Comment: Computers are not "magic" -- if Python is telling you that `opentab` is a `tuple`, then somewhere you have made it a tuple. As far as I can see it's not in the code you posted -- so you'll have to look around for it in the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Well mgilson, I'm using nested list because I need to store things like matrix  sequences here, while list is unhashable type.

Comment: Paul, I'll consider your advice. Actually It's a whole Best-First Search algorithm, reduce the code is hard for me T-T.

Comment: Joel, `NextStep()` returns list contains same type of element as     `opentab`.

Comment: I feel that the problem must be in `HerusticSort`, which isn't defined here. What does `HeuristicSort` do?

Comment: Also thanks, @katrielalex . You are right and I should be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only line in this program that could possibly change `opentab[0]` to a tuple -- under normal circumstances -- is `HeuristicSort`. Unfortunately, the source of `HeuristicSort` isn't here, so I can't be certain that's the problem. I'm posting this as requested, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 58 `opentab[0].append(subnode)` to `opentab[0].append(list(subnode))` should fix it.

The problem is that `subnode` is a `tuple` not a `list`.

Comment: This seems wrong. `assert isinstance(opentab[0], list)` asserts that `opentab[0]` is a list. `opentab[0].append(subnode)` appends `subnode` to the list `opentab[0]`. `opentab[0]` remains a list, and `isinstance(opentab[0], list)` remains true.

Comment: Your advice here is incorrect, but your comment above is right. I've retest the `HerusticSort`, and it changed element from list to tuple...

Comment: @senderle , would you write the answer below and then I can close this question ~

Comment: Oh, sorry @senderle. I read again. You post nothing incorrect. Thanks.